# Print variable from external file. NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, tkinter, module

I would like to get that: if I select item `A` in the combobox of `main.py`, then
the variable `example` is printed as placeholder in `phrase`
(both are located in the external file external.py). So I would like to simply get the phrase of external.py to be printed in the textbox in main.py.

[image]

The problem is that phrase is in an external file and does not recognize `x.get()`
in the condition, because x.get() is in the main file `main.py`, so
rightly it is undefined and I get the error:

```
    phrase =  ("{example}" if x.get() == "A" else "")
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

**external.py**

```
phrase =  ("{example}" if x.get() == "A" else "")
example = ("abcdefghilmno")
```

**main.py**

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

import external

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x150")

x=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 16)
x.place(x=15, y=10)
x['value'] = ["A", "B", "C"]
x.set("Item")

text = tk.Text(root,width=20,height=2)
text.place(x=15, y=50)

def write():
        
    text.delete(1.0,END)     
    text.insert(tk.END, external.phrase.format(example=example))

btn = Button(root, text="Print", command=write())
btn.pack()
btn.place(x=15, y=100)
 
root.mainloop()
```

**IMPORTANT**: I need the condition in the **same line** as the phrase and of the same code structure as much as possible to mine, because the code is part of my small personal project and if I change the code structure then nothing will work anymore.

Comment: Imported files can't access variables from the importing script. A module should be written so that it can be imported from any script, it shouldn't depend on the script having specific variable names. Put the code in a function that you call, passing `x` as an argument.

Comment: @Barmar Could you show me a response example of what you say? I'm not sure I understand. Also, you say that "it shouldn't", but unfortunately I need it this way: it means that even if it is not the correct way, I can still solve my problem?

Comment: @SantiagoE.98 - look at my answer below...

Comment: `command=write()` _immediately_ calls `write()`. It doesn't wait for the button to be clicked.

Comment: You solve it by passing `write` to the value of `command`: `command=write`

Comment: @BryanOakley I'm sorry I did not understand. What should I do? Thank you and sorry

Comment: He told you exactly. Change `command=write()` to `command=write`

Comment: @Barmar I thought I misunderstood. It's a spelling mistake, a distraction. This is not the main problem with my question. Even by modifying, obviously the main problem of the question is not solved. Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: The answer below answers the main problem, this is unrelated.

Comment: @Barmar Not really. In reference to the answer below, If in the write function I write text.insert (tk.END, external.phrase (x)), then the output will be {example}. Instead if write text.insert (tk.END, external.phrase (x)). Format (example = example) I get AttributeError: Object 'NoneType' has no 'format' attribute. I need to use format (example = example) as in my code. Can you advise me how to solve this little problem? Thank you

Comment: The questions you have asked and continue to ask seems to ignore what the viewers are trying to convey and continue to stick to what you say no matter what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code in `external.py` into a function, and call that from your `write()` function. Use `x.get()` in the main program, so that the module isn't dependent on your variable names or the fact that the main program uses Tkinter.

external.py:

```
example = "abcdefghilmno"
def format_phrase(template, testword, *params):
    return template.format(params) if testword == "A" else ""
```

main.py:

```
def write():
    text.delete(1.0,END)     
    text.insert(tk.END, external.format_phrase("{example}", x.get(), example=external.example))
```

Comment: Your code gives me the output {example} and not abcdefghilmno

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `f` for the f-string.

Comment: But don't really need formatting here, it can just return `example` directly.

Comment: As good as your solution is (and I thank you), in the question I asked for another type of answer similar to my code. The reason? The code of my application is part of a larger code of my project that I have already started some time ago. I would like to stick to my code, otherwise nothing works anymore. I would need to format as I already do in my code (although not the best way). I would need the placeholder {example} and format the text with .format (example = example)) in main. Could you also show me a workaround so please?

Comment: Your design is just backwards, you don't understand the proper way to design modules.

Comment: In practice I should print some text templates in main.py, while in external.py I have the various templates. For example I have template1 = {sentence1} {sentence2} {sentence3}. Then I later print templace1 in main.py formatting like this: text.insert (tk.END, external.phrase.format (example = example)). Everything works correctly. Your code I can't implement it in my code, that's why I wrote IMPORTANT at the bottom of my question. Could you help me with a workaround please? Thank you

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to use a template.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function in `external.py`:

```py
# external.py

def phrase(x):
    return ("{example}" if x.get() == "A" else "")
example = ("abcdefghilmno")
```

Then, in `main.py`

```py
# main.py

from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

import external

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x150")

x=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 16)
x.place(x=15, y=10)
x['value'] = ["A", "B", "C"]
x.set("Item")

PHRASE = external.phrase(x)
...
```

Comment: As you can see I use the write() function. How should I insert your PHRASE = external.phrase (x)? And the format? I'm waiting for your answer. Thank you

Comment: If in the write function I write text.insert (tk.END, external.phrase (x)), then the output will be {example}. Instead if I write text.insert (tk.END, external.phrase (x)). Format (example = example) I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'